# Exception javax.el.ELException occurs when I compare values in JSP

Tags: java, string, jsp, double, type-conversion

I have a jsp code as

```
<%
String n44rb= "p44_readback";
String reference44rb = ref.getDbTable(n44rb);
%>
<c:set var="reference44rb" value="<%=reference44rb%>"/>

<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback)}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.## " var="nf"></fmt:formatNumber>
<td style="${(nf lt 0 ? - (nf) : nf ) le reference44rb ? 'background-color: lime':'background-color: pink'}" >
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback)}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.## (" var="nn"></fmt:formatNumber>
<c:out value="${nn}"></c:out>
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback ne 0}">
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback)/r.p44_readback}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" type="percent" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
<c:out value="${mm}" ></c:out><c:out value=")"></c:out></c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<c:out value="00%)"></c:out>
</c:otherwise></c:choose></td>
```

The value of r.p44_readback is obtained from bean and the format of it is

```
Double  doubleValue = Double.valueOf(rs.getString(2));
                             String formattedValue = String.format("%.2f", doubleValue);
                             ref_obj.setBeam_current(formattedValue);
```

where ref_obj is class object.

when I run the above java code I'm getting error **Cannot convert -00.02  of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long** in td tag line 
But why this error,all the values are in string here.

**EDIT-1**
I changed **reference44rb** from string to float as

```
<%
String n44rb= "p44_readback";
float reference44rb = ref.getDbTable(n44rb);
%>
<c:set var="reference44rb" value="<%=reference44rb%>"/>

<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback)}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" var="nf" pattern="##.##"></fmt:formatNumber>
<td style="${(nf lt 0.0 ? - (nf) : nf) le reference44rb ? 'background-color: lime':'background-color: pink'}" >
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback)}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.## (" var="nn"></fmt:formatNumber>
<c:out value="${nn}"></c:out>
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback ne 0}">
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback)/r.p44_readback}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" type="percent" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
<c:out value="${mm}" ></c:out><c:out value=")"></c:out></c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<c:out value="00%)"></c:out>
</c:otherwise></c:choose></td>
```

I'm getting correct answer but now the problem is that when I do comapre
`<td style="${(nf lt 0.0 ? - (nf) : nf) le reference44rb ? '`in td tag and I put the value of **reference44rb** **as 0.01 and value of nf is also 0.01** ,then **pink color is displayed** but grreen should be displayed as I used le i.e less then equal to operator here and both the values are equal.
When I change the value of **reference44rb** to 0.014 then green colr is displayed.

Comment: `<c:when test="${r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback ne 0.0}">`

Comment: @JigarJoshi,whats in this c:when tag.Its correct.

Comment: I mean `0.0` instead of `0`

Comment: error is coming in td tag line

Comment: @JigarJoshi,when I do not comapre and do not write <fmt:formatNumber> tag before td ,den no error are coming but I need to trim my subtraction values before comparision with reference44rb

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style="${(nf lt 0 ? - (nf) : nf ) le reference44rb ? 'background-color: lime':'background-color: pink'}" >
```

'reference44rb' is a String variable. And you are using the 'le' operator on it.

Comment: ,I changed reference44rb to float <%
String n44rb= "p44_readback";
float reference44rb = ref.getDbTable(n44rb);
%>
<c:set var="reference44rb" value="<%=reference44rb%>"/>

Comment: As far as I can see, your problem is in this arithmetic comparison you do. By default JSTL coerces the variables to a 'double' value

Comment: yes,problem is in comparison only.See my edit above in qyuestion

Comment: Can you hard code .01 for both and test the output? Print the 2 values and check if they have more precision

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think there is issue here:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback)}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.## (" var="nn"></fmt:formatNumber>
```

It should be:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback)}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.##" var="nn"></fmt:formatNumber>
```

Comment: ,I want bracket with the pattern